# What type of file does "/path/to/your/key" refer to?

Tags: java, keyczar

I am using [Keyczar](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) and this is the psedo code on the website

```
 Crypter crypter = new Crypter("/path/to/your/keys");
 String ciphertext = crypter.encrypt("Secret message");
```

I know its the path to my encrpytion key but what type of file is it ??

What type of file are they refering to for `"/path/to/your/keys"`. ???

It will be good if I can have a sample of such a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create keys of your own. Simply follow the tutorial from the projects home page:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/keys
keyczart create --location=/tmp/keys --purpose=crypt
keyczart addkey --location=/tmp/keys --status=primary
```

Then you can refer to the key in your code:

```
Crypter crypter = new Crypter("/tmp/keys");
String ciphertext = crypter.encrypt("Secret message");
```

If you already have some private key (X.509), you can [import](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/CppTutorial#Importing_PEM_Private_keys) it.

Comment: I cant find the tutorial for Java , can i please have a link to it

Comment: It's pretty hard to miss, but here you go: https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/CppTutorial